# setOnDismissListener resulting in dismissed DialogFragment being reshown after config change

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

In my **Fragment**'s `onCreateView()` method, I call my `showHelp()` method to show a **DialogFragment**, employing an **OnDismissListener** so some other code can be executed when the dialog is dismissed:

```
protected void showHelp(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener onHelpDismissListener) {

    String helpTitle = getHelpTitle();
    String helpContent = getHelpContent();

    InfoDialog helpDialog = InfoDialog.newInstance(helpTitle, helpContent);
    helpDialog.showNow(getChildFragmentManager(), InfoDialog.TAG);
    Dialog dialog = helpDialog.getDialog();

    Log.d(TAG, "For helpDialog dialog, setting dismiss listener: " + onHelpDismissListener);
    if (onHelpDismissListener != null) {

        /*
         * When I remove this line, InfoDialog behaves properly - i.e., if it is dismissed, then
         * the device rotated, it is not displayed again.
         * 
         * Even when the onHelpDismissListener's `onDismiss()` method performs no action, the problem still occurs.
         */
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(onHelpDismissListener);
    }
}
```

However, the inclusion of the `dialog.setOnDismissListener(onHelpDismissListener);` line results in the dialog being displayed again on the UI after a config change, despite it having been previously dismissed.

If I remove that line, it behaves as it should do. (But, obviously, I don't get my callback.)

For completeness, here is my **InfoDialog** class:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

public class InfoDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = InfoDialog.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "ARG_TITLE";
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "ARG_MESSAGE";

    private InfoDialogViewModel mInfoDialogViewModel;

    public static InfoDialog newInstance(String title, String message) {

        InfoDialog infoDialog = new InfoDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        infoDialog.setArguments(args);
        return infoDialog;
    }

    @Override @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Null args!");
        }

        Context context = requireContext();

        mInfoDialogViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(InfoDialogViewModel.class);

        String title = args.getString(ARG_TITLE);
        String message = args.getString(ARG_MESSAGE);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(Utilities.fromHtml(context, title, this, null));
        builder.setMessage(Utilities.fromHtml(context, message, this, null));
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (DialogInterface dialog, int id) -> {
            mInfoDialogViewModel.setResult(InfoDialogViewModel.RESULT_OK);
        });

        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setOnCancelListener((DialogInterface dialog) -> {
            mInfoDialogViewModel.setResult(InfoDialogViewModel.RESULT_CANCELLED);
        });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Any ideas why this problem is happening? And how can I prevent the dismissed dialog from re-appearing after a config change?

Alternatively, is there another way to listen for the dialog being dismissed?

Comment: `DialogFragment` sets its own `OnDismissListener` on the `Dialog`, and it handles the `Fragment` removal there. When you set your `OnDismissListener` on the `Dialog`, it overrides `DialogFragment`'s listener, so that removal never happens, and the `FragmentManager` thinks the `DialogFragment` is still active after the configuration change. Instead, you'll need to override `DialogFragment`'s `onDismiss()` to get the dismiss event, and then handle your listener there, however you like; e.g., create a `setOnDismissListener()` method in `InfoDialog`, and call that listener from `onDismiss()`.

Comment: Ah, of course! :-) All sorted now. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.